# EmberJs - issue while binding value with template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Model data is not binding with template correctly. I am seeing result like this instead of actual values.

[image]

I have created [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YxG5c/) for this. So you can check. Click "Gender" / "Marital Status" to get above result.

**Router:**

```
App.FieldRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, Field) {
    controller.set('model', App.Fields);
  }
});
```

**Template:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="field">  
    {{#each model}}
    <div>
       <input type="text" style="margin: 10px" placeHolder="Key" value="{{key}}"/>
       <input type="text" style="margin: 10px" placeHolder="Desc" value="{{desc}}"/>
       <i class="icon-trash"></i>
    </div>    
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `{{key}}` and `{{desc}}` inside element attributes.
Correct way of binding element attributes described here http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-attributes/.

Template using correct syntax will be as follows:

**Template:**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="field">  
    {{#each model}}
        <div>
            <input type="text" style="margin: 10px" placeHolder="Key" {{bindAttr value="key"}}/>
            <input type="text" style="margin: 10px" placeHolder="Desc" {{bindAttr value="desc"}}"/>
            <i class="icon-trash"></i>
        </div>    
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

jsFiddle with working example: http://jsfiddle.net/dbERr/1/

You can also use built-in view [Ember.TextField](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextField.html), but it supports limited number of attributes that you can specify. E.g. it does not support `style` attribute out of the box.

Comment: Do you have any idea on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807230/emberjs-how-to-filter-array-and-pass-it-to-template-via-router)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Ember.Textfield](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.TextField.html)

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="field">  
    {{#each model}}
    <div>
       {{view Ember.TextField  placeHolder="Key" valueBinding="key"}}
       {{view Ember.TextField  placeHolder="Desc" valueBinding="desc"}}
       <i class="icon-trash"></i>
    </div>    
    {{/each}}
</script>
```