# EmberJS - How to filter array and pass it to template via router

Tags: ember.js

see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dbERr/2/).

I have array like this.

```
App.Fields = [{id: "Gender", desc: "Male", key: "M"}, 
                  {id: "Gender", desc: "Female", key: "F"}, 
                  {id: "Martial Status", desc: "Single", key: "S"}, 
                  {id: "Martial Status", desc: "Married", key: "M"}];
```

While my router executes i want to pass filtered array based model.id. Below is my router.

```
App.FieldRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, Field) {
    controller.set('model', App.Fields);
  }
});
```

When user clicks "Gender" i want to filter objects having id = "Gender" from the above array.

> FYI: model.id will give "Gender".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use .filterProperty() which returns the array with the matched property

```
controller.set('model', App.Fields.filterProperty('id',model.id));
```

will also do the trick

Answer (score 1):

This works.

```
App.FieldRoute = Ember.Route.extend({    
  setupController: function(controller, model) {   
    controller.set('model', App.Fields.filter(function(item, index, enumerable) {
        if(item.id === model.id) return true;
    }));
  }
});
```